# fb:visible-to-connection Not Working!

Tags: facebook, fbml

I don't usually deal in exclamation points, but I have hours before this goes live. I have the following page full of FBML for a Facebook tab on a product page:

```
<fb:fbml version="1.1">
    <div id="container" style="width: 520px;">
        <fb:visible-to-connection>
            <div>
                Yay!
                <a href="{link}" style="border: 0; display:inline-block;">
                    <img src="{image link}" style="border: none;" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <fb:else>
                <div>
                    <img src="{image link}" style="border: none;" />
                </div>
            </fb:else>
        </fb:visible-to-connection>
        <div class="{a css class I have to censor}">
            <img src="{image link}" />
            <p class="nopurchase" style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS Gothic', Arial; font-size: 10px;">
                some text.
                <a href="{link}" target="_blank">Click for something.</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</fb:fbml>
```

Basically it's a fan gate. To get past it the user has to like the page it resides on. It parses and renders, but for whatever reason *both* conditions (the div for fans, and the one for non-fans) are drawn. I have no idea why fb:visible-to-connection isn't doing this.

Comment: Does the Facebook app have to go through approval before this will work in a tab? I'm really racking my brain for ideas on what could be wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple. If you are an admin of the application you are using, visible-to-connection will show you everything, regardless whether you're a fan or not. Normal users will see the expected functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if you are an admin you get the trap all the time. If you go to the page with an account that is not an admin you can like the page and then see the content as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to ACCOUNT on the top right of your screen
2. Click USE FACEBOOK AS PAGE
3. Select another page, then check your functionality - this should work